# Split html links tag

Tags: c#, regex

I have this html code in a string:

```
  Hello world
  <img src="mypicture.png" />
  <p>Some text in a tag</p>
  <a href="http://www.google.fr">Link to google</a> Some Text <a href="http://www.yahoo.fr">Link to yahoo</a> End of line
  <p>Some text in a tag</p>
  <a attribute="some value" href="http://www.apple.com">Link to apple</a>
  Some text
```

I want to convert this string into this array:

```
  0 => Hello world
  <img src="mypicture.png" />
  <p>Some text in a tag</p>
  <a href="

  1 => http://www.google.fr

  2 => ">Link to google</a> Some Text <a href="

  3 => http://www.yahoo.fr

  4 => ">Link to yahoo</a> End of line
  <p>Some text in a tag</p>
  <a attribute="some value" href="

  5 => http://www.apple.com

  6 => ">Link to apple</a>
  Some text
```

I have tried this regexp. It works fine to extract the links, but i do not manage to build my array...

```
  <a (.*?)href=(.*?)\"(.+?)\"(.*?)>
```

Comment: Try for fun: `(?<=<a\s+[^>]*href=\")([^"]+)(?=\"[^>]*>)`

Comment: with regex.match ?

Comment: Use `Regex.Split`.

Comment: See [*Split List*](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%3ca%5cs%2b%5b%5e%3e%5d*href%3d%5c%22)(%5b%5e%22%5d%2b)(%3f%3d%5c%22%5b%5e%3e%5d*%3e)&i=+Hello+world%0d%0a++%3cimg+src%3d%22mypicture.png%22+%2f%3e%0d%0a++%3cp%3eSome+text+in+a+tag%3c%2fp%3e%0d%0a++%3ca+href%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.fr%22%3eLink+to+google%3c%2fa%3e+Some+Text+%3ca+href%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fwww.yahoo.fr%22%3eLink+to+yahoo%3c%2fa%3e+End+of+line%0d%0a++%3cp%3eSome+text+in+a+tag%3c%2fp%3e%0d%0a++%3ca+attribute%3d%22some+value%22+href%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fwww.apple.com%22%3eLink+to+apple%3c%2fa%3e%0d%0a++Some+text) section.

Comment: Did you handle it? Still need help?

Comment: In fact, i use my original regex and i worked with Index and Length information to split by my self. Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add something to capture anything and everything before the link as well:

`([\W\w]*?)(?:(<a .*?href=.*?\")(.+?)(?=\")|$)`

- Get every character until...
- Link is found:

  - Get the link up to the href value (basically your code)
  - Get the characters up to the next quote (the url)
- End of the text is found

Then you just need to step through each match and add the `pre + link` to the array, and the `url` to the array separately.